# How to check if an RGB image contains only one color?

Tags: python, image, colors, python-imaging-library

I'm using Python and PIL.

I have images in RGB and I would like to know those who contain only one color (say #FF0000 for example) or a few very close colors (#FF0000 and #FF0001).

I was thinking about using the histogram but it is very hard to figure out something with the 3 color bands, so I'm looking for a more clever algorithm.

Any ideas?

> ImageStat module is THE answer! Thanks Aaron. 
>   I use ImageStat.var to get the variance and it works perfectly.

Here is my piece of code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageStat

MONOCHROMATIC_MAX_VARIANCE = 0.005

def is_monochromatic_image(src):
    v = ImageStat.Stat(Image.open(src)).var
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x and y < MONOCHROMATIC_MAX_VARIANCE, v, True)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the [ImageStat module](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/imagestat.htm). If the values returned by `extrema` are the same, you have only a single color in the image.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should define a distance between two colors.
Then you just have to verify for each pixel that it's distance to your color is small enough.

Comment: Computing the Euclidian distance between each pixel in the 3 dimensions RGB space is theoreticaly fine, but I think it won't work with multi million pixels images... (at least in Python)

Comment: Why Euclidian distance? You can imagine something else depending on what you want.

Comment: The problem is not in the type of distance, but in the fact that the algorithm is O(N^2), N being the number of pixels in the image (I have cases with N=10,000,000)

Comment: Perhaps i misunderstood your question.
If you have to check that each pixel is close enough to a given color, it's linear time.

Comment: @Smuk: I don't think it's a given color -- the color they are all closest to could be anything, specific to each image, right?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little snippet you could make use of :

```
import Image

im = Image.open("path_to_image")
width,height = im.size

for w in range(0,width):
  for h in range(0,height):
     # this will hold the value of all the channels
     color_tuple = im.getpixel((w,h))
     # do something with the colors here
```

Maybe use a hash and store the tuples as the key and it's number of appearances as value?