# How to get color of area in picture

Tags: c#, image, colors

I have some picture, example:
 [image]

and i want to get color of area in picture. example 
[image]

but i don't know how to do that.

Comment: **No, Thank You!!** Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). Also, I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: hope this [link][1] helps you to find out the color of an area


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/684700/1858508

Answer (score 2):

First, you cannot "generally" get the color of an area (unless you average the color of the area or some other manipulation). You will be looking for the color of a specific pixel.

From your `Bitmap`, call `GetPixel` with the `X,Y` coordinates of the picture where you want to get the color. See documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel.aspx).

**Edit:** from the comments, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165107/how-do-i-invert-a-colour-color-c-net) to invert the color, this should be pretty straight forward from the `Color` returned by `GetPixel`

Comment: thanks for your comment. i've read that documentation. But GetPixel method is slowly. And after i get the color, i must be analyze color to add text on this area.

Comment: @HelloSun is it "too slow" for your usage?  What do you mean by analyze?

Comment: i mean, i need find color of image and reverse that color for the text will be added on it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [`Bitmap.GetPixel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel.aspx) method and see if that's appropriate; to get an entire region's colour you'll just have to write a loop that goes from the top left to bottom right pixel and does the operation.

Anything more specific we'd have to know if you're using Winforms or WPF or if you're just loading a straight bitmap from disk.

Comment: Oh no, i using console program to load image from disk, then add text to some picture. i need find color of image and reverse that color for the text.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://csharpmentor.blogspot.in/2009/05/get-rgb-color-at-point-in-image-with.html) one has an example to get the color at a point an image