# Swap RGB channel color using OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, image, opencv, colors, rgb

Naive question, I'm working with color processing for the first time.
I want to swap RGB channel from Mat image.
What I'm trying to do create another image from the original image and assign the R and G value as R. And then on another image, assign R and G value as G.
Here's my code :

```
Mat testcolor = imread("tulip.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
int rows = testcolor.rows;
int cols = testcolor.cols;

Mat leftimg(rows, cols, CV_8UC3);
Mat rightimg(rows, cols, CV_8UC3);

cvtColor(testcolor, testcolor, COLOR_RGB2BGR);
for (int i = 0; i < testcolor.rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < testcolor.cols; j++  ){ 
        leftimg.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0] = testcolor.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0];
        leftimg.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1] = testcolor.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0];
        leftimg.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[2] = testcolor.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[2];

        rightimg.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0] = testcolor.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1];
        rightimg.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1] = testcolor.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1];
        rightimg.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[2] = testcolor.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[2];
    }
}

cvtColor(leftimg, leftimg, COLOR_BGR2RGB);
imwrite("leftimg.png", leftimg);
cvtColor(rightimg, rightimg, COLOR_BGR2RGB);
imwrite("rightimg.png", rightimg);
```

But I don't think I got the result that I expected.
This is the original image.
[image: This is the original image]

and this is the reult image :
[image]

I expect something like, if I assign R and G as R --> The green part will have some red shades. And if I assign R and G as G, the red part will have some green shades. Did I miss something in my code ? or I'm lacking understanding ?

In this case, I dont have raw image, and I didn't convert my color space because I wanted to see how it worked with RGB. And then if needed I will convert the color space later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current implementation if RGB value at a pixel was say ( 100, 150, 200 ) on performing (R,G)->R conversion you will end up with value ( 100, 100, 200 ). So the pixel will have both Red and Green component.

But, I believe, what you want as a result, is an image with no green component in the pixels.

For that you would have to do something as follows for each pixel.

```
R = Function( R, G )
and 
G = 0
```

for each pixel.

Here the Function would represent the way you want to combine the R and G values of a pixel to form the new R value of that pixel.
And since you make G as 0, you wont have a green shade in that pixel.

Comment: Exactly what I need for my program now. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If we mixture different B-G-R components, we can get more than B-G-R. such as : `B(high)+G(high)+R(low) => Yellow`; `B(high)+G(low)+R(high) => Purple`.

Here is an example:

[image]

And the dependent channels are as follow:

[image]

Now go back to your flowers image, the big difference in `R` and `G` channels are the `Red flowers regions`. If you replace the `G` by `R`, then the regions become `B(low) + R(high) + R(high) => yellow`. If you replace the `R` by `G`, then  become `B(low) + G(low) + G(low) => dark`.

[image]

---

Here is a map of **Hue** in **HSV**. 
[image]

And an example to find green in HSV is here.

[How to define a threshold value to detect only green colour objects in an image :Opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47483951/how-to-define-a-threshold-value-to-detect-only-green-colour-objects-in-an-image/47483966#47483966)

Comment: You explanation saved me. How can we tell if a channel is High or Low ?

Comment: Generally speaking, you should convert to `HSV` to split the specific color(such as green). Maybe this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47483951/how-to-define-a-threshold-value-to-detect-only-green-colour-objects-in-an-image/47483966#47483966

Comment: I did convert my color space before, but I still need to decide if what I'm trying to do is best fit with RGB or HSV, that why I want to try with RGB too.

Comment: Then just try as you wish.