# How does filtering out the colors of a hsv image in opencv python work?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, hsv

I am working on a project that needs to identify the shape of an object in a field. My goal right now is to filter out any colors the background could be such as green, brown, or gray.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('pic1.png')
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

lower_green = np.array([0,0, 150])
upper_green = np.array([255, 255, 255])

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_green, upper_green)
res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

cv2.imshow('res1.png', res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The image

[image: enter image description here]]

is showing a sample of the shapes in the field.

This code results in this image:

[image: enter image description here]]

Why do the values I use for the lower and upper greens remove all the green when I have only included red values?

Are there any ways to get filters that remove only one color so I am able to pick and choose which colors I would want to keep and which to remove?

Comment: You're using a green range to generate a mask, then using the mask to erase entire pixels.

Comment: You did not "include red values" with `0,0, 150`. It would be red in CV2's BGR model, but you are applying it to an HSV image.

Comment: Here is a `hsv colormap`. [how-to-define-a-threshold-value-to-detect-only-green-colour-objects-in-an-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47483951/how-to-define-a-threshold-value-to-detect-only-green-colour-objects-in-an-image/47483966#47483966), maybe useful for understanding.