# Analyze an image in specific area and determine if it's red using Opencv Python

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, heatmap, color-detection

I'm using Opencv python in raspberry pi, to analize a heatmap, i'm looking for color red, which represents the highest temperature,  i need to detect if in an specific area exist red color, in case it does i can use this information to activate a condition, i'm using a heatmap like this:
[image]

for the red color detection i'm using this code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

while(1):

    # Take each frame

    frame = cv2.imread('heatmap.png')

    # Convert BGR to HSV
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # define range of blue color in HSV
    lower_red = np.array([-20, 100, 100])
    upper_red = np.array([13, 255, 255])

    # Threshold the HSV image to get only blue colors
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)


    # Bitwise-AND mask and original image
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= mask)

    cv2.imshow('heatmap',frame)
    cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
    cv2.imshow('res',res)
    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

the code above give me al the pixels in red, but i need to determine if the heatmap contour is red, i mean the image contour or border would be a red color not permited area, does anyone how i can do that?

Answer (score 1):

Your HSV range is not right. For red, `(0,20,20)~(8,255,255), (170,20,20) ~ (180,255,255)`.

---

Here is my result:

[image]

---

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# 2018/05/16 13:54:09 
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('heatmap.png')
# Convert BGR to HSV
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
mask1 = cv2.inRange(hsv, (0,20,20), (8,255,255))
mask2 = cv2.inRange(hsv, (170,20,20), (180,255,255))
mask = cv2.bitwise_or(mask1, mask2)
dst  = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)
cv2.imshow("dst", dst)
cv2.imwrite("__.png", dst)
cv2.waitKey()
```

> Some useful links:
>
> 1. [Choosing the correct upper and lower HSV boundaries for color detection with`cv::inRange` (OpenCV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948589/choosing-the-correct-upper-and-lower-hsv-boundaries-for-color-detection-withcv/48367205#48367205)
> 2. [How to define a threshold value to detect only green colour objects in an image :Opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47483951/how-to-define-a-threshold-value-to-detect-only-green-colour-objects-in-an-image/47483966#47483966)

Comment: i thank you so much, and i ask you something else, do you know how to determine the red color dots coordinates?? so i can use that information in an if