# Using python openCV detect object based on 2 color

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

Is it possible to use python openCV to detect and count human cell based on color?

For example, in this picture, I want to detect cell that positive blue and green separate from those blue and yellow.[image]

Comment: yes, you can definitely do that, but could you share your code snippet for what issue you are facing while implementing it ? or this was just a question to know yes or no ?

Comment: sorry I'm newbie in openCV what I know is detection based on 1 color but i dont know how to detect object basd on 2 color.

Comment: If blue is the common color then simply focus on green and yellow color segmentation ?

Comment: Here is [my result with specific color removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dK0dA.png) . [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47483951/how-to-define-a-threshold-value-to-detect-only-green-colour-objects-in-an-image/47483966#47483966) maybe help.

Comment: Blue is Staning for nuclear of the cell. So if green and yellow present without blue is don’t count.