# Obtaining binary mask of skin from bounding box

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

I have trained an object detection model to detect fingertips of hand. I have extracted the fingertips from the bounding box coordinates. Here is what I got:

[image] [image][image]

Now I want to get the binary mask from these images, which include only the region of fingertip. I have tried these approaches and did not get satisfactory results.

- Used canny edge detector approach.
- Used Grabcut approach.
- Normalized image, then extracted h channel from HSV to find the largest contour.

I want to extract the fingertip region from these bounding boxes, I am currently lost, will appreciate any leads in the right direction.

**EDIT**
Images with red background:

[image] [image]

Comment: if you already have the neural network and data to train it, you could also just train one to give you this **segmentation**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can opt for the [LAB color space](https://www.xrite.com/blog/lab-color-space).

One extreme of the A-channel identifies red color. Hence applying Otsu threshold on this extreme can isolate it pretty well.

**Code:**

```
img = cv2.imread('finger_1.png')

# convert to LAB color space
lab = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)

# apply Otsu threshold on A-channel
th = cv2.threshold(lab[:,:,1], 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

**Results:**

[image]  [image]
[image]

As a further option, you can try normalizing the same A-channel and proceed further.

Also have a look at [this post on how to segment green color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47483951/how-to-define-a-threshold-value-to-detect-only-green-colour-objects-in-an-image/72264323#72264323).

Comment: This worked perfectly on most of the images that I am testing on.

Comment: there is one case where this method fails and that is if we have red background, I think that's understandable as "A" channel corresponds to Red/Green value. Is there anyway we can make it work for such images as well?

Comment: I have added images with red background in question edit.

Comment: @MuhammadHassan You can try enhancing this method by also including edge detection