# Detect and create mask for color highlighted section on image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

How can I create a highlight mask for an image? I have attempted various methods, however, I have not been able to attain the desired outcome.

How to detect colored sections without any adverse effects on the pink colored section, or any other color such as yellow?

Input

[image]

Current output

[image]

Desired output

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def detect_highlighted_text(image_path):

    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    lower_pink = np.array([150, 50, 50])
    upper_pink = np.array([180, 255, 255])
    lower_red = np.array([0, 50, 50])
    upper_red = np.array([10, 255, 255])

    pink_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_image, lower_pink, upper_pink)
    red_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_image, lower_red, upper_red)

    combined_mask = cv2.bitwise_or(pink_mask, red_mask)

    highlighted_text = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=combined_mask)

    cv2.imshow("Highlighted Text", highlighted_text)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

detect_highlighted_text("path/to/your/image.jpg")
```

I tried to use create mask using inRange function, also searched about using [findCountors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75940723/create-masking-using-image-boundaries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You need a couple of [Morphological filters](https://docs.opencv.org/4.8.0/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html) and a little bit of tuning in your `HSV` thresholds. To obtain the final mask, you could also apply a [Flood-fill](https://docs.opencv.org/4.8.0/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga366aae45a6c1289b341d140839f18717) at one corner using white color. Something like this:

```
# Imports:
import cv2

# Set image path
directoryPath = "D://opencvImages//"

# Set image path:
imagePath = directoryPath + "41OzV.jpg"

# Load image:
inputImage = cv2.imread(imagePath)

# Convert the BGR pixel to HSV:
hsvImage = cv2.cvtColor(inputImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Threshold on red:
rangeThreshold = 5
lowerValues = np.array([0, 34, 153])
upperValues = np.array([179, 255, 255])

# Create HSV mask:
redMask = cv2.inRange(hsvImage, lowerValues, upperValues)
```

This gives you the following binary mask:

[image]

It’s alright, but it would benefit from some morphology. Apply a `Closing` first, to close the gaps and then an `Opening` to get rid of the small blobs of noise:

```
# Use a little bit of morphology to clean the mask:
# Set kernel (structuring element) size:
kernelSize = 3
# Set morph operation iterations:
opIterations = 3

# Get the structuring element:
morphKernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (kernelSize, kernelSize))

# Perform closing:
redMask = cv2.morphologyEx(redMask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, morphKernel, None, None, opIterations, cv2.BORDER_REFLECT101)

# Perform opening:
redMask = cv2.morphologyEx(redMask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, morphKernel, None, None, opIterations, cv2.BORDER_REFLECT101)
```

This will yield the following cleaned mask:

[image]

Now, let’s use this mask and `AND`it with the original image:

```
# Mask original image:
outputImage = cv2.bitwise_and(inputImage, inputImage, mask=redMask)
```

Which produces the following image:

[image]

Almost there, now let’s `flood-fill` at `(0,0)` (top left corner) to propagate white throughout the black color:

```
# Flood-fill at seed point:
seedPoint = (0, 0)
# Set new color and tolerance:
newColor = (255, 255, 255)
tolerance = (5, 5, 5)
cv2.floodFill(outputImage, None, seedPoint, newColor, loDiff=tolerance, upDiff=tolerance)
```

This is the final result:

[image]

Comment: I just wanted to take a moment to express my gratitude and appreciation for your effort! Thank you.